# Recombination due to crossover, outcome?

Tags: genetics

Garden peas normally have 7 pairs of chromosomes (n=7, 2n=14). Please calculate how many different types of gametes can be produced through the meiotic process if no crossover happens. If cross-over happens regularly, how many different types of gametes can be produced and why?

I have tried the question, I would suppose the answer to be 2 ^ 7 = 128 for the types of gametes that are produced( that is without crossing over).

However, I am not sure what is the solution what is the answer if cross over does happen. appreciate any solution to the problem.

Comment: The question asked for the number of gametes, not the recombination frequency (which cannot be 128 by the way, a frequency is by definition bounded between 0 and 1). For crossovers, the question is unclear as it depends on the crossover frequency and if recombination hotspots are present.